# Error when creating nested for loop in Terraform locals

Tags: terraform

this is the terraform var file.

```
endpoints = [
  {
    domain_name     = "my.domain.com"
    aws_region      = "us-east-2"
    custom_endpoints = {
      service = {
        endpoint_name    = "web",
        health_check_name = "web"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    domain_name = "my2.domain.com"
    aws_region  = "us-west-2"
    custom_endpoints = {
      service = {
        endpoint_name    = "web2",
        health_check_name = "web2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have the following terraform code.

```
  custom_endpoints = [ for each in var.endpoints : {
                        for key, value in each.custom_endpoints: 
                         key => {
                           for k, v in value: {
                             "${value.endpoint_name}.${each.domain_name}" => {
                                health_check_fqdn = "${value.health_check_name}.${each.domain_name}"
                                region = each.aws_region
                           }
                          }
                         }
                        }
                     ]
```

terraform plan produces the following:

```
Error: Missing key/value separator

  on locals.tf line 13, in locals:
  12:                            for k, v in value: {
  13:                              "${value.endpoint_name}.${each.domain_name}" => {

Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.
```

I update the code so that it uses "=" instead of "=>" as it suggests

```
  custom_endpoints = [ for each in var.endpoints : {
                        for key, value in each.custom_endpoints: 
                         key => {
                           for k, v in value: {
                             "${value.endpoint_name}.${each.domain_name}" = {
                                health_check_fqdn = "${value.health_check_name}.${each.domain_name}"
                                region = each.aws_region
                           }
                          }
                         }
                        }
                     ]
```

This now returns a new error.

```
Error: Invalid 'for' expression

  on locals.tf line 12, in locals:
  11:                          key => {
  12:                            for k, v in value: {
  13:                              "${value.endpoint_name}.${each.domain_name}" = {
  14:                                 health_check_fqdn = "${value.health_check_name}.${each.domain_name}"
  15:                                 region = each.aws_region
  16:                            }
  17:                           }
  18:                          }

Key expression is required when building an object.
```

I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is endpoints ?

Comment: @Marcin added endpoints to question. ty.

Comment: apologies for the poorly constructed question. i realized i was approaching this the wrong way. please disregard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra pair of `{}` which is not needed. Also its not exactly clear what do you expect to achieve with your for loops (they have other mistakes), but to make it just work, you can do:

```
custom_endpoints = [ 
    for idx, each in var.endpoints : {
      for key, value in each.custom_endpoints: 
       "${idx}-${key}" => {
         for k, v in value: 
           "${k}-${value.endpoint_name}.${each.domain_name}" => {
              health_check_fqdn = "${value.health_check_name}.${each.domain_name}"
              region = each.aws_region
         }
       }
      }
   ] 
}
```